# Error Msg is not showed up in WinDbg

Tags: locale, windbg, message, show

When I debug my app via WinDbg, I have some trouble.

I'm not sure whether it is a kind of WinDbg's bug or not.

sometimes I used to want to know about thread's last error.

I mean TEB's LastErrorValue and LastStatusValue.

also I know about !gle and !error commands belongs to WinDbg.

However, after putting in !gle or !error command, I can't see Result Message.

I guess it is related with locale issue. but I'm not sure.

following is the situation on my WinDbg.

```
0:000> !teb
TEB at 7ffdf000
...
LastErrorValue:       998
LastStatusValue:      c0000005

0:000> !gle -all
Last error for thread 0:
LastErrorValue: (Win32) 0x3e6 (998) -                                           .
LastStatusValue: (NTSTATUS) 0xc0000005 - "0x%08lx"               "0x%08lx"  

0:000> !error c0000005
Error code: (NTSTATUS) 0xc0000005 (3221225477) - "0x%08lx"               "0x%08lx"
```

actually, I'm using korean windows XP. so I guess I need to change Locale in WinDbg.

```
0:000> .locale e
Locale: English_United States.1252
0:000> !gle -all
Last error for thread 0:
LastErrorValue: (Win32) 0x3e6 (998) - Àß¸øµÈ ¸Þ¸ð¸® À§Ä¡¸¦ ¾×¼¼½ºÇÏ·Á°í Çß½À´Ï´Ù.
LastStatusValue: (NTSTATUS) 0xc0000005 - "0x%08lx"
```

but it made it worse as you see.

Inevitably I have to find the meaning of error value via Google. but it makes me bother.

It will be ok if I can see error message in english.

Is there anyone can help me about this?

Thank you for your any reply in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a bug to me...Not sure if there's anything you'll be able to do about this. You could write your own version of !gle, but that would be a pain. I'd provide feedback on the !gle command via the link at the bottom of the help page:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff563177(v=vs.85).aspx

Maybe there's a workaround they can provide you with.

-scott

Comment: thank you for your comment. I will contact with them via web page you mentioned.